# Can we add emojis to a enhanced rich text column inside a sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text

I have a question if sharepoint enhanced rich text field support adding emojis? i need emojis for:-

1. Green right arrow.
2. Red cancel arrow
3. yellow circle

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

On a Windows computer, you can use the Windows key + . (dot) to bring up the Emoji selector. Here you can type a word or scroll through the available emojis.

Some render fine in the enhanced rich text editor, others appear only in black, like the green tick mark.

There's a lot of moving parts involved here, i.e. standards, notations, Javascript, etc, which may play into the availability and rendering, especially since everything in SharePoint online is done with Javascript and there can be conflicts when it comes to introducing other Javascript heavy tools like the emoji selector.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By design, we can not add emojis to a **Enhanced Rich-Text** column inside a sharepoint online site.

**You can realize your design by inserting pictures in SharePoint Online**

1.Create a **Picture Library App**

[image]

2.Upload three picture to the **Picture Library**

[image]

3.Go to the specific List with Enhanced Rich-Text, click **▪▪▪** menu >> select **Insert image** >> paste the path of picture to the **Image address** textbox

[image]

4.**Effect picture**

[image]

Comment: You can't add emojis? what about the method I describe in my answer?